# Can't change DNS Server on Android

Tags: dns

I have few devices in my local network.
I want them to have names like in this example:

```
192.168.1.1    router.home
192.168.1.2    nas.home
192.168.1.3    rpi.home
```

I setup dnsmasq server on my NAS server (`192.168.1.2`) and edited router's DHCP config to have IP of NAS as first DNS resolver.

When I enter `nas.home/` on my desktop PC everything works fine, but Android phone on same network does not, even I see right settings in WiFi description (first DNS resolver is `192.168.1.2`, static IP etc.)

What can be problem? Even my notebook on WiFi works fine. Just phones not work.

Comment: Because Android loves Google, it must be sending DNS queries to `8.8.8.8`. Which Android version you are on? If it's Pie, disable Private DNS in settings. If you have root, force DNS queries to your server by: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.2:53`. Also clear DNS cache: `ndc resolver clearnetdns wlan0`.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Private DNS is turned off, cleanup not helped. Sure I can force it to use my dns but I dont want to do this on every Android Phone I have at home.